# How to modify configuration properties in Mean.js?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, cloud9-ide, mlab, meanjs

I am currently working in a cloud environment (cloud9) and have installed the Mean.js (http://meanjs.org/) package.

Following the tutorial at IBM (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-mean1/index.html) the final step involves running the application using grunt.

Now in order to run the default application I need to change a couple of properties as I am using a Cloud Database (MongoLab).

**My question is how I can change the properties, such as config.db, in the mean.js?** On their website they describe the following: http://meanjs.org/docs.html#configuration

However, there is no clear explanation in which file to do so or how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting the code, you will probably see several environment definition files (production, development etc). Those contain the mapping for the config variables, example:

```
db: process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || 'mongodb://' + (process.env.DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR || 'localhost') + '/mean',
```

so parameters are expected to be defined as environment variables.

For setting up mongodb you can specify either MONGOHQ_URL, MONGOLAB_URI or the DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR, for facebook App ID it looks for: clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_ID || 'APP_ID' etc.